# more pythonic way - pandas dataframe manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, series

Say I have a dataframe called `vals` as follows:

**id**..........**date**..........**min_date**..........**max_date**

1..........2016/01/01..........2017/01/01..........2018/07/01
2..........2017/02/02..........2017/01/01..........2017/04/01
3..........2016/05/01..........2016/01/01..........2016/07/01

I want to add a column called `within_range` that shows `True` if `date` is between `min_date` and `max_date` and `False` otherwise.

This is the code I have but am wondering if there's a more efficient way:

```
vals['within_range'] = False

for i in range(len(vals)):
    if vals.loc[i, 'date'] >= vals.loc[i, 'min_date']
          and vals.loc[i, 'date'] <= vals.loc[i, 'max_date']:

        vals.loc[i, 'within_range'] = True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
vals['within_range'] = vals['date'].between(vals['min_date'], vals['max_date'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Would that not just be:

```
vals['within_range'] = (
    vals['date'] >= vals['min_date'] &
    vals['date'] <= vals['max_date']
)
```